# Swift - Replace exact matching Characters / Words in String (not containing)

Tags: swift, string, replace, character

I have a string like this
`"c \\cdot c"`
this represents a string in latex. Printed in reality it would be `c · c`.

Now I want to replace the `c` because it is a variable. Like
`c = 2`
with the result `2 · 2`.

I thought about doing something like

```
let string = "c \\cdot c"
let replacingString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "c", with: "2")
print(replacingString) // "2 \\2dot 2"
```

That is not exactly what I was aiming at. But I expect that there should exist a not-selfmade solution to this because Xcode supports searching patterns like these these:
[image: Xcode search options]

The "*matching word*" should be able to solve the problem. But is there anything in swift that is already provided? If not I would go something like this. But it is not very handy:

```
let string = ":c: \\cdot :c:"
let replacingString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: ":c:", with: "2 ")
print(replacingString)  // "2 \\cdot 2"
```

Kind regards

## Continued

After the input of Dávid Pásztor I was trying this. Just to share some experimental results.

```
let string = "c \\cdot c"
string.replacingOccurrences(of: "c", with: "2", options: .anchored, range: nil)             // c \\cdot c
string.replacingOccurrences(of: "c", with: "2", options: .backwards, range: nil)            // 2 \\cdot c
string.replacingOccurrences(of: "c", with: "2", options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil)      // 2 \\2dot 2
string.replacingOccurrences(of: "c", with: "2", options: .diacriticInsensitive, range: nil) // 2 \\2dot 2
string.replacingOccurrences(of: "c", with: "2", options: .forcedOrdering, range: nil)       // 2 \\2dot 2
string.replacingOccurrences(of: "c", with: "2", options: .literal, range: nil)              // 2 \\2dot 2
string.replacingOccurrences(of: "c", with: "2", options: .numeric, range: nil)              // 2 \\2dot 2
string.replacingOccurrences(of: "c", with: "2", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)    // 2 \\2dot 2
```

## Finally

To solution is:

```
let string = "c \\cdot c"
let replacingString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\bc\\b", with: "2", options: .regularExpression)
print(replacingString)  // "2 \\cdot 2"
```

Thanks a lot to Dávid Pásztor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `replacingOccurences(of:with:options:)` and pass `.regularExpression` to `options`. You also need to pass a regex to `of:` now instead of just passing the substring you want to replace. The correct regex here if `\\bc\\b`, which matches a word boundary before and after `c` ensuring that it's just the char `c` you are matching and not a `c` that's part of a word/expression.

```
let string = "c \\cdot c"
let replacingString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\bc\\b", with: "2", options: .regularExpression)
print(replacingString)  // "2 \\cdot 2"
```

Comment: Hello Dávid. Thank you for your support. Your solution is very helpful. I would suggest to fix the print line ```print(replacingString)  // "2 \\cdot 2"```. I did test it on Playground and noticed, that it is ```print(replacingString)  // ":2: \\cdot :2:"``` Just to prevent some confusion. Kind regards

Comment: @AlexanderLanger actually copied the wrong `string` from your question, updated my answer to contain the `string` without the `:` in it.